# Pandas if-else "join" function returns ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, pandas-groupby

Below is the example of my dataset:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═══════════════╗
║   ║ col_1      ║ col_2         ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 106        ║ I am Alex.    ║
║ 2 ║ 106        ║ I'm a student ║
║ 3 ║ 106        ║ I like apple  ║    
║ 4 ║ 1786       ║ Dog is a pet  ║
║ 5 ║ 1786       ║ Jack is my pet║
╚═══╩════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

and I would like to first groupby "col_1" and then join the string in "col_2" with the if-else condition of finding the last character in the string whether it is ended with "."

If it is ended with a fullstop, join the next string of the same group with " ".join (join them with a space).
Else, join them with a fullstop.

End result will look something like this:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║   ║ col_1      ║ col_2                                    ║
╠═══╬════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 106        ║ I am Alex. I'm a student. I like apple   ║
║ 2 ║ 1786       ║ Dog is a pet. Jack is my pet             ║
╚═══╩════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

My code is stated as below:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['col_1'])['col_2'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x) if x[-1:] == '.' else '. '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

However I got this error instead:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: x[-1:] returns the last element as a list instead of an element. Just use x[-1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming none of your strings have trailing spaces, why not just apply `'. '.join(...)` and remove the doubled results?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [106,106,106,1786,1786],
    'col2': ['I am Alex.','I\'m a student','I like apple','Dog is a pet','Jack is my pet']
})

result = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).agg({'col2': lambda x: '. '.join(x)})
result['col2'] = result['col2'].str.replace('.. ', '. ', regex=False)
```

This gets you, as expected:

```
   col1                                    col2
0   106  I am Alex. I'm a student. I like apple
1  1786            Dog is a pet. Jack is my pet
```

Comment: Thank you for that! Can I suggest another scenario where there are trailing spaces in list some of the list items? Eg: I am hardworking \nsmart \nhappy student, I live in US. What should I code instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('col_1')['col_2'].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat()).reset_index()
```